# Python3.6 on CentOS certificate verify failed

Tags: python, django, ssl, centos, redhat

My Django application is currently running on Python 3.4. I want to move it to 3.6, but I have an issue with SSL certificates.
The same application works perfectly fine on python 3.4. It still works fine with python3.6 within Docker container and on Windows PC. The only problem is with CentOS and RedHat (both 6.5).
My OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013.

Full error:

```
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:749)>
```

What can I do to fix that? The problem is only for python 3.6.0 and python 3.6.1. Python 3.4 works fine with that code.

Comment: Can you post more details about how you're actually integrating the SSL? Typically with Django, this is handled with the web server (i.e. Nginx) and Django plays little part in it. I've setup SSL with Django before on Python 3.4, 3.5, and 3.6 on Ubuntu and Amazon Linux (CentOS flavor) all the same way with no trouble.

Comment: Where did you get your Python 3.6 build?

Comment: The SSL certificate is handled on the otherside, I'm trying to connect to our corporate login service and python can't verify SSL fo it. Python 3.6 was installed by our IT department.